# How to match accented characters in a regex?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, gsub

I have this block of text defined as new_text bellow and i have a gsub block that runs through the text and should replace this bit

```
@[James Andrés Trento D.](content:25)
```

with

```
@James
```

However, with their being a é in the name its the \w isn't matching the word. I have tried using

```
[:alpha:]
```

without any luck. Does anyone know how I can get my regular expression to match accents?

```
new_text = "I have a video of @[James Andrés Trento D](content:25) dancing, but too big! May 5 - 9."

new_text.gsub! /@\[(?<name>[\w\s\-\']+)\]\(content:(?<userid>\d+)\)/ do
  m = $~
  name, id = m[:name], m[:userid]
  "@#{name.split(' ').first}"
end
puts new_text
```

Comment: try `\p{L}` instead of `[[:alpha:]]`

Comment: what's wrong with `\[(?<name>[^\]]*)\]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of possible solutions is to accept all not `]` symbols as part of name:

```
@\[(?<name>[^\]]+)\]\(content:(?<userid>\d+)\)
            ^^^ <- match all not `]` symbols
```